# Why does the debugger say Frame.Content is null here

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm used to WinForms, so this isn't behaving quite how I'd expect. In the code below, ActiveView is a Frame, Register is Page. I want to load the register page into the ActiveView and then change the text on a button. Even though the page loads, the debugger says that `ActiveView.Content == null` in SetCloseButtonText. Why is that?

```
private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            SwapActiveView(Register);
        }

        public void SwapActiveView(Page NewPage)
        {
            if (ActiveView.Content == null || !ActiveView.Content.Equals(NewPage))
            {
                if (ActiveView.Content != null)
                {
                    PreviousViews.Add((Page)ActiveView.Content);
                }
                ActiveView.Content = NewPage;
            }
            else
            {
                ActiveView.Content = NewPage;
            }

            SetCloseButtonText();
        }

        private void SetCloseButtonText()
        {
            if (PreviousViews.Count == 0 && ActiveView.Content == null)
            {
                tbCloseButton.Text = "Close";
            }
            else
            {
                tbCloseButton.Text = "Back";
            }

        }
```

Comment: Did you step through the code to see what is happening? Put a breakpoint at the beginning of SwapActiveView then single-step to see what is happening. Are you sure that NewPage is not null? If none of that helps then you need to provide more information.

Comment: Stepping through, it hits the first `ActiveView.Content = NewPage;` then goes to the `SetCloseButtonText();` This is where I'm confused. Is there something about WPF that makes it not set the Content until the button click function completes?

Comment: Did you look at NewPage? If ActiveView.Content is not null and NewPage is null then ActiveView.Content will be set to null, correct? Also, you should look at ActiveView.Content at the **beginning** of SwapActiveView.

Comment: I thought the same thing. The first if statement of SwapActiveView has ActiveView.Content = null and NewPage is set to an instantiation of the page I want to show. Which all works fine, it's just not picking up the content in the SetCloseButtonText call. Also if I call SwapActiveView a second time the content is set to the NewPage instantiation

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer. A frame navigates asynchronously, whether you call the navigate function or just change the content. So I simply needed to add the method and call my function then.

```
private void ActiveView_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        SetCloseButtonText();
    }
```

Comment: I assume that single-stepping through the code helped you to isolate the problem.

Comment: It did, but I needed to understand the controls I was using better.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know if that will help anyone in the future but it might.